# JavaScript Changing the script

Tags: javascript

I changed color to background-color and now JavaScript stopped working, how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select');
    document.getElementById('my-select').value='<?php echo $ats; ?>';

    var setBgColor = function (select) {
        select.style.background-color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].style.background-color;
    };
    mySelect.onchange = function () {
        setBgColor(this);
        document.searchform.submit();
    };
    if(-1 != mySelect.selectedIndex) { 
        setBgColor(mySelect);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `background-color` with `backgroundColor`. JS uses [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) when handling CSS properties.

That means that you also have to write `paddingLeft`, `whiteSpace` etc. in Javascript.

Comment: We all were beginners once (I'm so deep).